# Looking for childhood social SF book name, around 80s, near or alternate future in England

Tags: story-identification, novel, dystopia

The Protagonist is a suave, charismatic young man and his girl, ending up being persecuted by a rigid dystopian future state. 
Some details I remember:

- Featuring a possibly sympathetic military officer (who is an old family friend/acquaintance) driving a jaguar.
- which gets hijacked on a highway by hooligans. Being military, it's got an emergency button calling in a gurkha special force unit in helicopters. The hooligans are heading straight for organ transplant vats.
- There is a tea ceremony metaphor, illustrating the pathological state of today's job market - if you can cook tea perfectly in front of an auditorium of white-coats you get the coveted job of assistant to some secret guy.
- on a motorbike, the young man and his girl head out of London north into the countryside, where life is still worth living and people are friendly.
- on the way, they have to hide in some cave and sedate themselves to avoid detection by police and their brainwave scanners.
- They also do some rite-of-passage by jumping through a ring of fire.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Great start. Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and see if you can remember anything else. The more you are able to share, the more likely we can help.

Comment: `The young man and his girl head out of London north into the countryside, where life is still worth living and people are friendly.`
This does not sound like sci-fi :)

Comment: @JeremyFrench Of course not. All Sci-Fi stories have worlds where life is not worth living and people are mindless automatons under control of the state police. That trip includes the need to elude `brainwave scanners` which I suppose is also not Sci-Fi?

Comment: @Gypsy Spellweaver was an attempt at humour, about whether fleeing London to the north where life is worth living was any different to reality.

Comment: @JeremyFrench Of course it is, in the story the brainwave scanners could be fooled by drugs.

Comment: Note moderator comment confirming validity of OP confirmation comment for answer below.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds very like *Futuretrack 5* by Robert Westall. While I haven't read it in over 30 years, the themes sound right. They had psycho-copters and psycho-scanners, a motorbike escape into the countryside with a girlfriend.

[Bookrags overview](http://www.bookrags.com/shortguide-futuretrack-5/setting.html#gsc.tab=0) and [Google books](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=aOmtsqRcS7gC) link which lets you read a few pages in. There doesn't seem to be a digital copy available sadly but it's still fairly widely available (online) as a used paper based item.

Comment: Fantastic man, franki. That's the one, thanks. As you said, probably 30 years, but this book kept popping up in my mind, especially the tea scene.
(op)

Comment: Mod note: The above comment from the user claiming to be the OP (user ID 88690) does seem to be from the OP (user ID 88348).